# UniSharp File manager not working with Laravel 7

Tags: authentication, laravel-7, unisharp-file-manager

I have recently implement tinyMCE and I am using UniSharps file manager to handle files when i attempt to test the file manager I get Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given error.
I have tried some solutions such as going into the config/lfm.php file and editing the middlewares option to be 'middlewares' => [] and i have tried removing this option as well and I have tried 'middleware' => ['web','auth'] in the Route:group.
I do have my own custom guards being used but I removed them from this route in case it was interfering but it still shows the same error, and just in case I also cleared the routes and the config but that didn't work either.
I am using laravel 7.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by changing 'middleware' => ['web','auth'] to 'middleware' => ['web','auth:Admin'] since I was using a different guard